# Problem initiating SIP session/ getClientTransaction(request) throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, voip, sip, jain-sip

I have a small issue, I had my SIP client working, and I changed the structure of the code. I kept the creation process of the SIP objects as it was before, but now it does not work.

I keep getting:

**java.lang.NullPointerException    at gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.getNewClientTransaction(SipProviderImpl.java:285)**

and there is no reference to such error in the documentation... what does it mean?

here is the instantiation code for the sip:

```
        sipFactory.setPathName(host);
        sipFactory.resetFactory();
        sipStack = sipFactory.createSipStack(getProperties());
        String address = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
        sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
        sipFactory.createMessageFactory();

        udpPoint = sipStack.createListeningPoint(address, SIPPort, SIPConstants.UDP);
        udpSipProvider = sipStack.createSipProvider(udpPoint);
        udpSipProvider.addSipListener(this);

        tcpPoint = sipStack.createListeningPoint(address, SIPPort, SIPConstants.TCP);
        tcpSipProvider = sipStack.createSipProvider(tcpPoint);
        tcpSipProvider.addSipListener(this);

        sipStack.start();
        setSessionState(SipSessionState.Connected);
```

Any Help please??

Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWW

If anyone would had ever guessed this, I'll eat my LapTop....

in the first project I was using the Jain-Sip 1.2
and in the new one I use the 1.2.1

BIG issue that in the **1.2**, as far as I can tell, **request.getMethod()** returns the method of the **CSeq header** in case I don't use the **request.setMethod(method)**.

While in the **1.2.1**, if not setting the **request.setMethod(method)**, the **request.getMethod()** method returns null.

that was my error...

now if you read this please commend or something... I'm so frustrated, I was sitting on this bugger for 4 hours now. Damn.

Adam.

Comment: I still can't believe that was the bug... very deep debugging really!